# Subcaption in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, subcaption

After adding the sub-caption, my figures aligned vertically from the horizontal position. Initially, my first three figures were aligned horizontally and at the last figure was below the first three figures. I tried with subfigure but still not working.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
%\begin{subfigure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[scatter/classes={
    %a={mark=square*,blue},%
    %b={mark=triangle*,red},%
    a={mark=triangle,draw=blue,fill=red}},width=0.3\linewidth, xlabel=Normalized execution time, ylabel=NCD]

    % \addplot[] is better than \addplot+[] here:
    % it avoids scalings of the cycle list
    \addplot[scatter,only marks,
        scatter src=explicit symbolic]
        coordinates {
            (0.2439,0.786)  [a]
            (0.2368,0.782) [a]
            (0.2488,0.792) [a]
            (0.245,0.8)  [a]
            (0.2278,0.69)   [a]
            (0.2318,0.679)   [a]
            (0.3069,0.8156) [a]
            (0.2264,0.795) [a]
            (0.3905,0.7813) [a]
            (0.4977,0.7937) [a]
            (0.1996,0.3484) [a]
            (0.20344,0.3592) [a]
            (0.186575,0.6627) [a]
            (0.1875,0.676) [a]
            (0.240,0.710)  [a]
            (0.452,0.783)   [a]
            (0.520,0.807)   [a]
            (0.255,0.615) [a]
            (0.399,0.7913) [a]


        };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\subcaption{SHA}
%\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
\hspace{3mm}\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[scatter/classes={
    %a={mark=square*,blue},%
    %b={mark=triangle*,red},%
    a={mark=triangle,draw=green,fill=red}}, width=0.3\linewidth,xlabel=Normalized execution time, ylabel=NCD]

    % \addplot[] is better than \addplot+[] here:
    % it avoids scalings of the cycle list
    \addplot[scatter,only marks,
        scatter src=explicit symbolic]
        coordinates {
            (0.2481,0.7963)  [a]
            (0.0979,0.7619) [a]
            (0.0600,0.586) [a]
            (0.2454,0.8025)  [a]
            (0.0366,0.2289)   [a]
            (0.2540,0.7921)   [a]
            (0.05877,0.644) [a]
            (0.2776,0.7055) [a]
            (0.2404,0.7858) [a]
            (0.0581,0.4022) [a]
            (0.2189,0.786) [a]
            (0.1426,0.616) [a]
            (0.259,0.8207) [a]
            (0.0363,0.2289) [a]
            (0.063,0.4182)  [a]
            (0.2052,0.7587)   [a]
            (0.0954,0.4884)   [a]
            (0.3049,0.7367) [a]
            (0.08015,0.6383) [a]
            (0.4344,0.747) [a]
            (0.4188,0.7418) [a]
            (0.2044,0.5975) [a]
            (0.0679,0.4271) [a]
            (0.3049,0.7367)  [a]
            (0.205,0.7587)   [a]
            (0.0679,0.427)   [a]
            (0.30494,0.7367) [a]
            (0.205,0.7587) [a]
            (0.2592,0.8207)  [a]
            (0.2052,0.758)   [a]
            (0.3049,0.736)   [a]
            (0.0801,0.63837) [a]    
            };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\subcaption{blowfish}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture} \hspace{5mm}
\begin{axis}[scatter/classes={
    %a={mark=square*,blue},%
    %b={mark=triangle*,red},%
    a={mark=triangle,draw=red,fill=red}},width=0.3\linewidth,xlabel=Normalized execution time, ylabel=NCD]

    % \addplot[] is better than \addplot+[] here:
    % it avoids scalings of the cycle list
    \addplot[scatter,only marks,
        scatter src=explicit symbolic]
        coordinates {
            (0.290323,0.713)  [a]
            (0.267,0.6116) [a]
            (0.271,0.70) [a]
            (0.3015,0.623)  [a]
            (0.316,0.7155)   [a]
            (0.192,0.6456)   [a]
            (0.3093,0.7457) [a]
            (0.3351,0.7364) [a]
            (0.205,0.6687) [a]
            (0.2954,0.747) [a]
            (0.168,0.5053) [a]
            (0.26037,0.6145) [a]
            (0.2678,0.614) [a]
            (0.177,0.515) [a]
            (0.2695,0.617)  [a]
            (0.2670,0.6213)   [a]
            (0.230,0.637)   [a]
            (0.2611,0.607) [a]
            (0.2867,0.533) [a]
            (0.2653,0.633) [a]
            (0.257,0.5372) [a]
            (0.2718,0.5391) [a]
            (0.1893,0.4286) [a]
            (0.1881,0.43)  [a]
            (0.198,0.4313)   [a]
            (0.256,0.459)   [a]
            (0.161,0.323) [a]
            (0.160,0.323) [a]
            (0.1609,0.366)  [a]
            (0.232,0.8276)   [a]
            (0.3256,0.7945) [a]
            (0.1345,0.6789) [a]
            (0.3546,0.8356)  [a]
            (0.4345,0.814)  [a]
            (0.3986,0.8098)   [a]
            (0.423,0.643) [a]
            (0.4034,0.7567) [a]
            (0.4546,0.8134)  [a]
            };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\subcaption{blowfish}
\end{subfigure}

\vspace{1cm}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture} \hspace{6cm}
\begin{axis}[scatter/classes={
    %a={mark=square*,blue},%
    %b={mark=triangle*,red},%
    a={mark=triangle,draw=gray,fill=red}},width=0.3\linewidth,width=0.3\linewidth,xlabel=Normalized execution time, ylabel=NCD]

    % \addplot[] is better than \addplot+[] here:
    % it avoids scalings of the cycle list
    \addplot[scatter,only marks,
        scatter src=explicit symbolic]
        coordinates {
            (0.1005,0.617)  [a]
            (0.1064,0.6429) [a]
            (0.112,0.6814) [a]
            (0.11065,0.6847)  [a]
            (0.1121,0.6685)   [a]
            (0.1086,0.6630)   [a]
            (0.1138,0.5973) [a]
            (0.4284,0.8154) [a]
            (0.3465,0.7735) [a]
            (0.1145,0.6801) [a]
            (0.4906,0.80218) [a]
            (0.111,0.6295) [a]
            (0.5058,0.7998) [a]
            (0.4527,0.7906) [a]
            (0.5545,0.81309)  [a]
            (0.49602,0.8021)   [a]
            (0.49227,0.7362)   [a]
            (0.5326,0.758) [a]
            (0.2365,0.7786) [a]
            (0.3168,0.8013) [a]
            (0.2127,0.7637) [a]
            (0.3096,0.8106) [a]
            (0.4263,0.7926) [a]
            (0.5216,0.7156)  [a]
            (0.2357,0.7816)   [a]
            (0.1567,0.6023) [a]
            (0.178,0.616) [a]
            (0.363,0.698) [a]
            (0.456,0.801) [a]
            (0.307,0.726) [a]
            (0.526,0.819) [a]
            (0.163,0.783)  [a]


            };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\subcaption{MD5}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Plot of execution time and NCD value of benchmarks}
\label{fig:cp}

\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: First of all, lose the \hspace.  I'm not even sure what \hspace INSIDE a tikzpicture will do.  Now, how exactly do you want these to align?

Comment: Three will not fit side by side for this page geometry.  You can set up 2 rows of two using 0.5\textwidth.

Comment: I want 1row of 3 and the last one in the second row. But 2 rows of two will also suffice.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how to set up for a 2x2 matrix.  Note that inside the subfigure both `\linewidth` and `\textwidth` are reset to the subfigure width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}% debugging tool
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{position=above}% reduce gap between picture and caption
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[scatter/classes={
    %a={mark=square*,blue},%
    %b={mark=triangle*,red},%
    a={mark=triangle,draw=blue,fill=red}},width=0.6\linewidth, xlabel=Normalized execution time, ylabel=NCD]

    % \addplot[] is better than \addplot+[] here:
    % it avoids scalings of the cycle list
    \addplot[scatter,only marks,
        scatter src=explicit symbolic]
        coordinates {
            (0.2439,0.786)  [a]
            (0.2368,0.782) [a]
            (0.2488,0.792) [a]
            (0.245,0.8)  [a]
            (0.2278,0.69)   [a]
            (0.2318,0.679)   [a]
            (0.3069,0.8156) [a]
            (0.2264,0.795) [a]
            (0.3905,0.7813) [a]
            (0.4977,0.7937) [a]
            (0.1996,0.3484) [a]
            (0.20344,0.3592) [a]
            (0.186575,0.6627) [a]
            (0.1875,0.676) [a]
            (0.240,0.710)  [a]
            (0.452,0.783)   [a]
            (0.520,0.807)   [a]
            (0.255,0.615) [a]
            (0.399,0.7913) [a]


        };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\subcaption{SHA}
\end{subfigure}% no space between subfigures
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[scatter/classes={
    %a={mark=square*,blue},%
    %b={mark=triangle*,red},%
    a={mark=triangle,draw=green,fill=red}}, width=0.6\linewidth,xlabel=Normalized execution time, ylabel=NCD]

    % \addplot[] is better than \addplot+[] here:
    % it avoids scalings of the cycle list
    \addplot[scatter,only marks,
        scatter src=explicit symbolic]
        coordinates {
            (0.2481,0.7963)  [a]
            (0.0979,0.7619) [a]
            (0.0600,0.586) [a]
            (0.2454,0.8025)  [a]
            (0.0366,0.2289)   [a]
            (0.2540,0.7921)   [a]
            (0.05877,0.644) [a]
            (0.2776,0.7055) [a]
            (0.2404,0.7858) [a]
            (0.0581,0.4022) [a]
            (0.2189,0.786) [a]
            (0.1426,0.616) [a]
            (0.259,0.8207) [a]
            (0.0363,0.2289) [a]
            (0.063,0.4182)  [a]
            (0.2052,0.7587)   [a]
            (0.0954,0.4884)   [a]
            (0.3049,0.7367) [a]
            (0.08015,0.6383) [a]
            (0.4344,0.747) [a]
            (0.4188,0.7418) [a]
            (0.2044,0.5975) [a]
            (0.0679,0.4271) [a]
            (0.3049,0.7367)  [a]
            (0.205,0.7587)   [a]
            (0.0679,0.427)   [a]
            (0.30494,0.7367) [a]
            (0.205,0.7587) [a]
            (0.2592,0.8207)  [a]
            (0.2052,0.758)   [a]
            (0.3049,0.736)   [a]
            (0.0801,0.63837) [a]    
            };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\subcaption{blowfish}
\end{subfigure}\vspace{1cm}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[scatter/classes={
    %a={mark=square*,blue},%
    %b={mark=triangle*,red},%
    a={mark=triangle,draw=red,fill=red}},width=0.6\linewidth,xlabel=Normalized execution time, ylabel=NCD]

    % \addplot[] is better than \addplot+[] here:
    % it avoids scalings of the cycle list
    \addplot[scatter,only marks,
        scatter src=explicit symbolic]
        coordinates {
            (0.290323,0.713)  [a]
            (0.267,0.6116) [a]
            (0.271,0.70) [a]
            (0.3015,0.623)  [a]
            (0.316,0.7155)   [a]
            (0.192,0.6456)   [a]
            (0.3093,0.7457) [a]
            (0.3351,0.7364) [a]
            (0.205,0.6687) [a]
            (0.2954,0.747) [a]
            (0.168,0.5053) [a]
            (0.26037,0.6145) [a]
            (0.2678,0.614) [a]
            (0.177,0.515) [a]
            (0.2695,0.617)  [a]
            (0.2670,0.6213)   [a]
            (0.230,0.637)   [a]
            (0.2611,0.607) [a]
            (0.2867,0.533) [a]
            (0.2653,0.633) [a]
            (0.257,0.5372) [a]
            (0.2718,0.5391) [a]
            (0.1893,0.4286) [a]
            (0.1881,0.43)  [a]
            (0.198,0.4313)   [a]
            (0.256,0.459)   [a]
            (0.161,0.323) [a]
            (0.160,0.323) [a]
            (0.1609,0.366)  [a]
            (0.232,0.8276)   [a]
            (0.3256,0.7945) [a]
            (0.1345,0.6789) [a]
            (0.3546,0.8356)  [a]
            (0.4345,0.814)  [a]
            (0.3986,0.8098)   [a]
            (0.423,0.643) [a]
            (0.4034,0.7567) [a]
            (0.4546,0.8134)  [a]
            };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\subcaption{blowfish}
\end{subfigure}% no space
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[scatter/classes={
    %a={mark=square*,blue},%
    %b={mark=triangle*,red},%
    a={mark=triangle,draw=gray,fill=red}},width=0.6\linewidth,xlabel=Normalized execution time, ylabel=NCD]

    % \addplot[] is better than \addplot+[] here:
    % it avoids scalings of the cycle list
    \addplot[scatter,only marks,
        scatter src=explicit symbolic]
        coordinates {
            (0.1005,0.617)  [a]
            (0.1064,0.6429) [a]
            (0.112,0.6814) [a]
            (0.11065,0.6847)  [a]
            (0.1121,0.6685)   [a]
            (0.1086,0.6630)   [a]
            (0.1138,0.5973) [a]
            (0.4284,0.8154) [a]
            (0.3465,0.7735) [a]
            (0.1145,0.6801) [a]
            (0.4906,0.80218) [a]
            (0.111,0.6295) [a]
            (0.5058,0.7998) [a]
            (0.4527,0.7906) [a]
            (0.5545,0.81309)  [a]
            (0.49602,0.8021)   [a]
            (0.49227,0.7362)   [a]
            (0.5326,0.758) [a]
            (0.2365,0.7786) [a]
            (0.3168,0.8013) [a]
            (0.2127,0.7637) [a]
            (0.3096,0.8106) [a]
            (0.4263,0.7926) [a]
            (0.5216,0.7156)  [a]
            (0.2357,0.7816)   [a]
            (0.1567,0.6023) [a]
            (0.178,0.616) [a]
            (0.363,0.698) [a]
            (0.456,0.801) [a]
            (0.307,0.726) [a]
            (0.526,0.819) [a]
            (0.163,0.783)  [a]
            };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\subcaption{MD5}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Plot of execution time and NCD value of benchmarks}
\label{fig:cp}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

This shows how to pack them in as tight as possible.  The problem with getting three in one row was due to the xlabel and ylabel taking up too much space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}% debugging tool
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{position=above}% reduce gap between picture and caption
\lineskip=1cm
\centering
\sbox0{\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize]
\begin{axis}[scatter/classes={
    %a={mark=square*,blue},%
    %b={mark=triangle*,red},%
    a={mark=triangle,draw=blue,fill=red}},width=0.3\textwidth, xlabel=Normalized execution time, 
    ylabel=NCD, ylabel near ticks]
    % \addplot[] is better than \addplot+[] here:
    % it avoids scalings of the cycle list
    \addplot[scatter,only marks,
        scatter src=explicit symbolic]
        coordinates {
            (0.2439,0.786)  [a]
            (0.2368,0.782) [a]
            (0.2488,0.792) [a]
            (0.245,0.8)  [a]
            (0.2278,0.69)   [a]
            (0.2318,0.679)   [a]
            (0.3069,0.8156) [a]
            (0.2264,0.795) [a]
            (0.3905,0.7813) [a]
            (0.4977,0.7937) [a]
            (0.1996,0.3484) [a]
            (0.20344,0.3592) [a]
            (0.186575,0.6627) [a]
            (0.1875,0.676) [a]
            (0.240,0.710)  [a]
            (0.452,0.783)   [a]
            (0.520,0.807)   [a]
            (0.255,0.615) [a]
            (0.399,0.7913) [a]


        };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\sbox1{\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize]
\begin{axis}[scatter/classes={
    %a={mark=square*,blue},%
    %b={mark=triangle*,red},%
    a={mark=triangle,draw=green,fill=red}}, width=0.3\textwidth,xlabel=Normalized execution time,
    ylabel=NCD, ylabel near ticks]

    % \addplot[] is better than \addplot+[] here:
    % it avoids scalings of the cycle list
    \addplot[scatter,only marks,
        scatter src=explicit symbolic]
        coordinates {
            (0.2481,0.7963)  [a]
            (0.0979,0.7619) [a]
            (0.0600,0.586) [a]
            (0.2454,0.8025)  [a]
            (0.0366,0.2289)   [a]
            (0.2540,0.7921)   [a]
            (0.05877,0.644) [a]
            (0.2776,0.7055) [a]
            (0.2404,0.7858) [a]
            (0.0581,0.4022) [a]
            (0.2189,0.786) [a]
            (0.1426,0.616) [a]
            (0.259,0.8207) [a]
            (0.0363,0.2289) [a]
            (0.063,0.4182)  [a]
            (0.2052,0.7587)   [a]
            (0.0954,0.4884)   [a]
            (0.3049,0.7367) [a]
            (0.08015,0.6383) [a]
            (0.4344,0.747) [a]
            (0.4188,0.7418) [a]
            (0.2044,0.5975) [a]
            (0.0679,0.4271) [a]
            (0.3049,0.7367)  [a]
            (0.205,0.7587)   [a]
            (0.0679,0.427)   [a]
            (0.30494,0.7367) [a]
            (0.205,0.7587) [a]
            (0.2592,0.8207)  [a]
            (0.2052,0.758)   [a]
            (0.3049,0.736)   [a]
            (0.0801,0.63837) [a]    
            };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\sbox2{\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize]
\begin{axis}[scatter/classes={
    %a={mark=square*,blue},%
    %b={mark=triangle*,red},%
    a={mark=triangle,draw=red,fill=red}},width=0.3\textwidth,xlabel=Normalized execution time, 
    ylabel=NCD, ylabel near ticks]

    % \addplot[] is better than \addplot+[] here:
    % it avoids scalings of the cycle list
    \addplot[scatter,only marks,
        scatter src=explicit symbolic]
        coordinates {
            (0.290323,0.713)  [a]
            (0.267,0.6116) [a]
            (0.271,0.70) [a]
            (0.3015,0.623)  [a]
            (0.316,0.7155)   [a]
            (0.192,0.6456)   [a]
            (0.3093,0.7457) [a]
            (0.3351,0.7364) [a]
            (0.205,0.6687) [a]
            (0.2954,0.747) [a]
            (0.168,0.5053) [a]
            (0.26037,0.6145) [a]
            (0.2678,0.614) [a]
            (0.177,0.515) [a]
            (0.2695,0.617)  [a]
            (0.2670,0.6213)   [a]
            (0.230,0.637)   [a]
            (0.2611,0.607) [a]
            (0.2867,0.533) [a]
            (0.2653,0.633) [a]
            (0.257,0.5372) [a]
            (0.2718,0.5391) [a]
            (0.1893,0.4286) [a]
            (0.1881,0.43)  [a]
            (0.198,0.4313)   [a]
            (0.256,0.459)   [a]
            (0.161,0.323) [a]
            (0.160,0.323) [a]
            (0.1609,0.366)  [a]
            (0.232,0.8276)   [a]
            (0.3256,0.7945) [a]
            (0.1345,0.6789) [a]
            (0.3546,0.8356)  [a]
            (0.4345,0.814)  [a]
            (0.3986,0.8098)   [a]
            (0.423,0.643) [a]
            (0.4034,0.7567) [a]
            (0.4546,0.8134)  [a]
            };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\sbox3{\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize]
\begin{axis}[scatter/classes={
    %a={mark=square*,blue},%
    %b={mark=triangle*,red},%
    a={mark=triangle,draw=gray,fill=red}},width=0.3\textwidth,xlabel=Normalized execution time,
    ylabel=NCD, ylabel near ticks]
    % \addplot[] is better than \addplot+[] here:
    % it avoids scalings of the cycle list
    \addplot[scatter,only marks,
        scatter src=explicit symbolic]
        coordinates {
            (0.1005,0.617)  [a]
            (0.1064,0.6429) [a]
            (0.112,0.6814) [a]
            (0.11065,0.6847)  [a]
            (0.1121,0.6685)   [a]
            (0.1086,0.6630)   [a]
            (0.1138,0.5973) [a]
            (0.4284,0.8154) [a]
            (0.3465,0.7735) [a]
            (0.1145,0.6801) [a]
            (0.4906,0.80218) [a]
            (0.111,0.6295) [a]
            (0.5058,0.7998) [a]
            (0.4527,0.7906) [a]
            (0.5545,0.81309)  [a]
            (0.49602,0.8021)   [a]
            (0.49227,0.7362)   [a]
            (0.5326,0.758) [a]
            (0.2365,0.7786) [a]
            (0.3168,0.8013) [a]
            (0.2127,0.7637) [a]
            (0.3096,0.8106) [a]
            (0.4263,0.7926) [a]
            (0.5216,0.7156)  [a]
            (0.2357,0.7816)   [a]
            (0.1567,0.6023) [a]
            (0.178,0.616) [a]
            (0.363,0.698) [a]
            (0.456,0.801) [a]
            (0.307,0.726) [a]
            (0.526,0.819) [a]
            (0.163,0.783)  [a]
            };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{\wd0}
\usebox0
\subcaption{SHA}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{\wd1}
\usebox1
\subcaption{blowfish}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{\wd2}
\usebox2
\subcaption{blowfish}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{\wd3}
\usebox3
\subcaption{MD5}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Plot of execution time and NCD value of benchmarks}
\label{fig:cp}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo2]